# How to start a background task with the new Swift Structured Concurrency?

Tags: swift, async-await

I'm writing a test in Swift. The function that I'm testing blocks the current thread so I want to run it on the background. Previously I would wrap it in `DispatchQueue.global.async {}`.

With Swift's new structured concurrency, I found `Task.detached`. However, the notes on it say

> Creating detached tasks should, generally, be avoided in favor of using `async` functions, `async let` declarations and `await` expressions

Is there another Apple recommended way to start something asynchronously when it doesn't have the `async` flag?

Comment: Thanks @Rob. I missed that part. Do you want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is just telling you that in many cases, structured concurrency should be preferred, but where you need unstructured concurrency, feel free to use it.

That having been said, rather than creating a detached task, you can just start an unstructured task. See [The Swift Programming Language: Concurrency: Unstructured Tasks](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html#ID643). In short, rather than creating a detached task with `Task.detached { … }`, you can just use `Task { … }`